# In linear regression, does the formula for error contain the marginal expectation or conditional expectation?

Tags: regression, linear-model, error

In linear regression, let $\epsilon_i$ be the $i$th error term. Is the formula for $\epsilon_i$

1. $\epsilon_i = Y_i - E(Y_i)$

or

2. $\epsilon_i = Y_i - E(Y_i | X_i = x_i)$?

I have seen both definitions.

Penn State University uses Definition #1[1].

Iain Pardoe uses Definition #2 in Section 2.1 in his 3rd edition of "Applied Regression Modeling".

[image]

**Which one is correct?**

[1]: [Link to PennState](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/4/4.1#:%7E:text=Each%20observed%20residual,)

Comment: In a different PennState course, they use definition 2 (https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat508/lesson/3/3.4).

Comment: Good catch @wzbillings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both notations are fine, just depending whether you are thinking of a joint probability or not.

If you are thinking about the joint probability of $X_i$ and $Y_i$, then technically $E[Y_i] = E[X_i] \beta$, and so you would want to use the notation $E[Y_i | X_i = x_i] = x_i \beta$.

However, typically in linear regression we do not think $X_i$ as random but rather has a fixed value. If $X_i$ is a fixed, then $E[Y_i] = X_i\beta$, so that's correct in the case that we don't consider $X_i$ to be random.

Comment: Thank you. I am NOT using random covariates, so E(Y_i) is what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed time and again here and as noted in Cliff AB's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/643223/362671), there are two aspects about the assumptions of regressors, which can be seen in the case of simple linear regression model:

$\bullet $ When the independent variable is controlled by the experimenter and hence it is nonstochastic:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[Y]&= \beta_0+\beta_1X,\\\mathbb V[Y]&=\sigma^2.\end{align}$$

$\bullet$ When both the dependent and independent variables are stochastic that is $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed:

If the joint distribution is bivariate normal, then

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]&=\beta_0+\beta_1x,\\\mathbb V[Y\mid X]&=\sigma^2_{y\cdot x}\\&=\sigma^2_y(1-\rho^2).\end{align}$$

---

### Reference:

$\rm[I]$ Linear Models and Generalizations: Least Squares and Alternatives, *C. R. Rao, H. Toutenburg, Shalabh, Christian Heumann,* Springer-Verlag, $2008, $ sec. $2.1, 2.15.$