Normality of residuals in panel data
I ran a linear regression containing country- and year-fixed effects from a sample containing panel data (country by year).
Since I'm using OLS, do my residuals have to look approximately normally distributed over the entire sample or do they have to look like this for each country? So, the question is: Does the assumption of normality apply to the residuals of the model over the entire sample or for each individual entity?

Normality of residuals is not required for OLS; this is a long-standing myth.  OLS is the Best Linear Unbiased Estimator (BLUE) regardless of the distribution of the residuals as long as they have a finite variance.  Normality of the residuals gains you the benefit of various commonly-used tests, e.g., t- and F-tests having their exact distribution even with small sample sizes.

This question has high resemblance with the one asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643304/in-linear-regression-do-the-errors-overall-have-a-normal-distribution-or-do-th

In general, normality must hold (but also see jbowman's comment) for each combination of values of your independent variables, meaning in your case: for each country in each year!
As example, if you would only use "country" dummies (no years involved) and there are three countries, with means 1, 5 and 18, and for for each country the data would be normally distributed, as in the following histogram:

then the condition of normalty would be met, although the total distribution of the data (in the three countries together) is clearly far from normal (having three modes instead of óne to mention just one thing).
